# Using Dictionary (hashing) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

- I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets.
- I have to get counts of certain entries by using filters(i'm searching text instead of using filters here)
- The "Main" sheet is where the count is updated. The strings are searched from other sheets in the workbook
- The cells where the count should be updated varies.
- The search criteria,keyword,sheet,range, etc is given in the sample code which I have posted.

Example from code:

In Cell, AE43, the count is updated only when the sheet "TT" meets the criteria mentioned.

So, similarly I'll have to use the same kind of code 30+ times for different cells to get the data.

So instead of typing the code for similar search, I want to know whether we can use "Dictionary" function (hashing in other languages) here, so that a cell can be updated automatically if it meets the criteria.

```
Sub WBR()
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                'no of tickets processed - summary
[AE43] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT", _
                  .Range("G:G"), "<>Not Tested", _
                  .Range("U:U"), "Item")
 End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                'not tested tickets - summary
[AE44] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Not Tested")
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                'Tickets moved back- outdated OS and App Versions - summary
[AE45] = wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Outdated App Version") + wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Outdated OS")
End With
```

Comment: Yes, dictionary type is available to VBA (not on MAC OS though) via e.g., `Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` but I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: To tell in the manual way  - I'm just applying filters in different sheets and selecting certain text and getting the count and updating the count in "sheet1" . This task i have now automated in vba. You can find the sample excel file here [link]https://expirebox.com/download/5d2fe6f97f7097860cbc0208a663ecd6.html

Comment: dont try to write C#/Java style code in VBA.its an overkill, makes your code ugly and un-readable.

Comment: I fail to see what a Dictionary can achieve here. What would be desirable is to find a way to factorize the code and minimize it (to avoiding writing custom code for each cell). But the problem is that these calculations are so different that it seems difficult to understand what they have in common.

Comment: Yes, the text to be searched does not have anything in common here. What would be the best way to avoid writing custom code for each cells? Is it possible to make the code loop through the code and update cells if it meets the condition?

Comment: This is the fifth time you've posted essentially the same question asking about "hashing", but it's been totally unclear all along how a Dictionary would be useful here.  Maybe try looking at what you're doing and try to generalize your code to a parameterized subroutine which you can call repeatedly and just vary the arguments.  You could store the settings in rows on a worksheet and have your code loop over them to call the subroutine. On re-reading: what @A.S.H said

Comment: I'm stuck at this point. Im not sure how to vary the arguments here..which are nothing but the search keyword, col name,range etc.

Comment: Based on your example code, you have the following parameters: (1) a destination cell,(2) a source worksheet, (3) one or more pairs of criteria (col+string) and (4) how to combine multiple criteria (add individually or multi-match)

Comment: Correct..Im not sure how to convert this into a working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic example which should get you started.

Sub showing how to call the code:

```
Sub Tester()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
        .Range("A1") = GetCount("TT", False, "A:A", "Blue")
        .Range("A2") = GetCount("TT", False, "A:A", "Blue", "C:C", "Red")
        .Range("A3") = GetCount("TT", True, "A:A", "Blue", "C:C", "Red")
    End With


End Sub
```

Generalized version of your use cases:

```
'If addValues is True and there are >1 set of criteria then 
'   sum up a bunch of COUNTIF(), else use COUNTIFS() so all 
'   criteria are applied at the same time
Function GetCount(shtName As String, addValues As Boolean, _
                                           ParamArray crit()) As Long

    Dim sht As Worksheet, f As String, num As Long, i As Long
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)'<< counting things on this sheet
    num = UBound(crit)

    If num = 1 Or addValues Then
        f = "COUNTIF(" & crit(0) & ",""" & crit(1) & """)"
    End If

    If num > 1 Then
        If addValues Then
            'already got the first pair: add the rest
            For i = 2 To num Step 2
                f = f & " + COUNTIF(" & crit(i) & ",""" & crit(i + 1) & """)"
            Next i
        Else
            f = "COUNTIFS("
            For i = 0 To num Step 2
                f = f & crit(i) & ",""" & crit(i + 1) & """"
                If i <> num - 1 Then f = f & ","
            Next i
            f = f & ")"
        End If
    End If

    If f <> "" Then
        Debug.Print f
        GetCount = sht.Evaluate(f) '<<do not use Application.Evaluate here
    Else
        GetCount = -1 '<< something went wrong...
    End If

End Function
```

Debug output:

```
COUNTIF(A:A,"Blue")
COUNTIFS(A:A,"Blue",C:C,"Red")
COUNTIF(A:A,"Blue") + COUNTIF(C:C,"Red")
```

Probably could use some error-handling and if there are other use cases you'll need to add those in.

Comment: What does "False" and "True" does?

Comment: That gets passed to "addValues" in the called procedure.  See the comment there.

Comment: @TimWilliams  just for learning, `'<<do not use Application.Evaluate here` why?

Comment: `Application.Evaluate` will evaluate the formula in the context of the `ActiveSheet`, which might *not* be the sheet we want. The `Worksheet.Evaluate` version uses the context of the specified sheet.

Comment: So through this code I just need to declare the range, sheetname,searchstring in the sub itself?

Comment: Yes you just need to write another form of "Tester"

Comment: So if there are 100 cells then I need to specific everything in another sub? Pls correct me if im wrong.

Comment: A longer "Tester" with 100 calls to `GetCount`

Comment: Sorry if I have not understood the code correctly. I have to costume spceific everything inside a sub including the cell,keyword,range etc and the function below will just add it?

Comment: Try it out then post back if you run into problems.

Comment: Yes i tried it. It works good..just trying to understand what does the below function does?

Comment: It creates a worksheet formula (as shown in the Debug output) and then executes it against the specified worksheet.